# How can I add > 200Mb/2h tracks to iPhone with iCloud Music Library enabled?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music

I have a bunch of music tracks that are either longer than two hours or larger than 200Mb (DJ sets) that I'd like to play from my iPhone, along with a whole lot of "normal"-length music. These large tracks are not supported by iCloud Music Library.

How can I sync these large tracks to my phone once I enable iCloud Music Library?

(I realise this may functionally be a duplicate of [some](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234400/how-to-add-music-from-itunes-to-my-iphone-after-enabling-icloud-music-library) [previous](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361246/can-i-have-a-library-with-icloud-music-library-enabled-and-one-with-it-disabled) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197404/how-do-transfer-mp3-files-to-iphone-that-is-configured-with-icloud-music-library) but I'm hoping the "long DJ sets" framing is a solved problem for somebody.)

Comment: Files maybe is one option.. not so convenient as having an organised library

Comment: Will they end up as part of my music library, and searchable and playable from the Music app if I add them via Files?

Comment: sadly, no.. That's what I meant by *inconvenience*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s still not possible so I’ve worked around the problem by removing the long tracks from my music library and managing them with [Evermusic](https://www.everappz.com/evermusic) instead. Seems to be working well so far.